# PHP several curl requests after one is finished

Tags: php, curl

I want to create a login for my website with curl to manage some stuff.
Therefore I have to make multiple curl requests with the same cookies

Now I wonder what code is better to achieve this.
Is this better:

```
$CookieFile = 'cookies/'. uniqid() . '.txt';
file_put_contents($CookieFile, '');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $PostData1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $CookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $CookieFile);
$result1 = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $PostData2);
$result2 = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Or is it better to do it like this

```
$CookieFile = 'cookies/'. uniqid() . '.txt';
file_put_contents($CookieFile, '');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $PostData1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $CookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $CookieFile);
$result1 = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $PostData2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $CookieFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $CookieFile);
$result2 = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I'm not quite sure which version is better, I'm a bit worried about the cookies.
Or is there even a better version I didn't think of?

Answer (score 0):

First one is better, as it can utilize `Keep-Alive`.

The second option opens/closes http connection every time, and this TCP handshake is time consuming

NB: This is only relevant to connections made to same server, of course...

Answer (score 0):

Use the first one with addition of the following curl options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "valid user agent");
```